# Run batch file remotely using ssh and copy the result to a text?

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, expect

I need to run a batch script remotely using `ssh` and `expect` and copy the result to a text file. How do I do that?

This works:

```
 $ ssh -t username@dshost 'D:\scripts\a.bat' >file.txt
```

But this doesn't:

```
#! /usr/bin/expect --
spawn ssh -t username@shost  'D:\\scripts\\a.bat' >file.txt
expect "*assword:*" { send "pwd\r" }    
expect "yes/no"     send "yes\r"
exit
```

I am getting the following error.

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Comment: Have u tried `/d:/scripts/a.bat` ?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but change `exit` to `expect eof`

Comment: The folders have different names in the two commands. It can't finds script**s**.

Comment: That was a typo. I've edited the code in the question.
Changed exit to expect eof - Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Does spawn run cmd, if not it is command that does redirection.

```
cmd /c command >file
```